# Incy IdDayTime Connection problem

Tags: indy

I created some software which is using some kind of selfmade license files under Delphi 5 Enterprise. The license expires after a certain time to prevent further use. As it is easy to adjust any desired date on a PC I am trying to get a connection to an internet timeserver.

I tried several codes I found in the internet, none worked. My last try was installing the Indy components and using some simple code like the following:

IdDayTime1.Host := .... desired timeserver
IdDayTime1.Connect;
Label1.Caption := IdDayTime1.DayTimeStr;
IdDayTime1.Disconnect;

I always do not get a connection to a timeserver. This happens in different network areas (at work, at home,...), even if all typical internet software (like firefox, IE,...) works very well in all these networks. So I am sure to have a proper internet connection.

What might be the reason for my problems ?
Do I have to define some special details like ports or sth. else ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Indy did you use?  Which time server are you using?  There are several different date/time protocols on the internet.  TIdDayTime implements the [Daytime Protocol (RFC 867)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0867.txt), which is meant for retreiving human-readable date/time strings.  For machine-parsable date/time data, especially if you intend to update the PC's clock with it, then use TIdSNTP ([Simple Network Time Protocol, RFC 2030](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2030.txt)) or TIdTime ([Time Protocol, RFC 868](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0868.txt)) instead.